# Excel Concatenate with limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Worksheet which contains:

*WS1*

```
FIRST NAME          LAST NAME
testfirstname       testlastname
```

I'm looking to concatenate both columns using only the first 7 letters from the FIRST NAME and first 1 letter from the last name.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data begins in A1:

```
=LEFT(A1,7)&LEFT(B1,1)
```

If you also need a space between the two parts it would be:

```
=LEFT(A1,7)&" "&LEFT(B1,1)
```

Neither formula will compensate if there are fewer than seven characters in the first piece of data, so for example **Bill Smith** would come out as **BillS**.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore spaces in the FIRST NAME -- don't want spaces to count as the total 7?

Comment: Yes, try `=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),7)&LEFT(B1,1)`. This assumes that you want to remove the spaces and count your seven characters after that, not leave the spaces in the result but don't count them.